# System cannot find the path specified

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015, failed-installation

I need to use visual studio 2015 to do some scripting in the unreal engine four.

It is said the latest version of visual studios is needed.

I have downloaded the web installer, and then installed visual studio.

However there is a big problem,

[image: The problem]

In order to use auto completion, and other features that visual studio uses as a database to store files of a project, I need this "...SQL Server...". but the error says the system cannot find it.

What is the problem here, and the fix.

Note: [Common issues and workarounds0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3039361) does not contain the solution.

Comment: I think you can install the feature later if prefer.

Comment: @TheProHands I have downloaded this, all it does is extract it into my documents area i think.

Comment: YES. Can't you open it in VS/import to project?

Comment: I will try this. Import to project, understood.

Comment: @TheProHands I'm getting nowhere with this, any other ideas?

Comment: Did you get it working? Then it's okay. *Better than installing VS again, >.>*

Comment: PS: Now I did get what you said. If you can't get it by reinstalling Visual Studio again, then try to not add this feature and use another database type, like from phpmyadmin, etc. I'm not so experienced with C#/Visual Studio 2015 yet, but it's what I can suggest and enough. You can try sqlite too, but not safe.

Comment: @TheProHands the problem is that I'm not using database types. It's just that the Unreal Engine relies on this, with out it I am useless and unable to do any work. I do not know why, but this is needed or auto intelisense does not work, and it's very very frustrating as development time is extended. I have posted the same question on the UE4 forum, and Microsoft forums, but no replies.

Comment: Try to make bound for this question so someone who could help you appears.

Comment: Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983341(v=vs.110).aspx. Try to reinstall Visual Studio without checking any SQL checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution was to do a fresh install.

After reinstalling the OS (Windows 10 Enterprise), I was able to install visual studio.